# How to receive an array from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array of scores and names on firebase I want to receive the array and put it into an array. I followed what the documentation said and ended up with this...

```
 databaseRef.child("Leaderboard").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childChanged, with: {
    snapshot in 

let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
//Add data to variables


}
```

But `value` is being casted as a dictionary and I have two arrays that I want to receive how would I access them without mixing them?

My Firebase hierarchy looks like this

```
Leaderboard
        Scores
           50
           47
           ... //Continues
        Names 
           John Doe
           BOB
           ...//Continues
```

Comment: Can you add the console log of `print(value)`

Comment: when I `print(value)` I get nil, But if I print snapshot.value I get `Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x608000248610>(John Doe, BOB // and so on))` and the same thing for the scores. @Nirav D

Comment: @fellowProgrammer What do you mean by "the same thing for the scores"? It is printing two optional array?

Comment: It is printing two optional arrays. The Name array looks like what I posted before and the Scores array looks almost the same just with different values, `Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x608000051d30>(178, 66 // and so on))`.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No, the answer below does not work, it crashes. @NiravD

Comment: Is it printing nested array with two array?

Answer (score 5):

Write a for each and cast it to an `Array`

```
var yourArray = [Int]()
            if let scores = snapshot.value as? NSArray{
                for i in 0..<scores.count {
                    yourArray.append(scores[i] as! Int)
                }
            }
```

Do the same for `Names`

Comment: I think `for i in 0..<scores.count` should be `for i in 0..<snapshot.childrenCount`

Comment: What does "Do the same for `Names`" mean how do I specify the names array instead of the scores array @AtaerCaner

Comment: Can you share a screen of your database structure. I can help you with a  visual much more@fellowProgrammer

Comment: I have posted my database structure above.@AtaerCaner

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an array from firebase you cast as [Type]

`"array_firebase"` is the key from firebase document

In this example is an array of Strings:

```
let array = data["array_firebase"] as? [String] ?? []
```